# Using Managed Attributes to implement DRY principle

Tags: python, django, properties, keyword-argument

I have the following code in my models.py which works fine.

```
def get_city_name(self):
    return self.city.name

def get_state_name(self):
    return self.state.name

class AuthorMeta(Page):
    author=models.OneToOneField(User)
    city = models.ForeignKey('Cities', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='related_author')
    state = models.ForeignKey('States', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='related_author')
    city_name = property(get_city_name)
    state_name = property(get_state_name)
```

But I want to achieve the same with a single function.
I'm basically having problem with passing the arguments. Even if I try the following, it doesn't works:

```
def get_name(self, attr):
    return getattr(self, attr)

class AuthorMeta(Page):
    ##### city, state, etc. defined here #####
    city_name = property(get_name('city'))
    state_name = property(get_name('state'))
```

It results in a different error, `get_name() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)`

Comment: `kwargs` is a dictionary of keyword arguments, don't you just need a plain argument, e.g. `p`. You would then `return getattr(self, p).name`. But you will need `functools.partial` to create the property object, `city_name = property(partial(get_name, 'city'))`...

Comment: yup. that worked. `partial` is exactly what i was looking for. Thanks a ton